# Simple login system requires you to login on index.php

Tags: php

I have this simple password system (not a full login system) that requires you to type in a password upon viewing the page  (access.php)

On my main website page, index.php, I want to include my simple password page just so I can read if there are any open sessions. My main issue is, when I include my access.php it, replaces the whole file index.php with access.php. All I did was:

```
<?php
include("access.php");
?>
```

I have tried a lot of methods but none of them seem to work.

Is there a way I can read any open sessions from access.php without including or requiring that page?

**EDIT**
Here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/Dsq6EKuC

Comment: include your code in index.php and access,php so we can see what's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `index.php` you can check if there is an active session. Make sure you use `session_start()` first.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
    // do something with your active session
}
```

If the session is active then it will be set on subsequent page loads and you can check for it.

Comment: lol, ofc! Should've known this xD

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.